# Adding a button to dynamically added flex-item in flex-box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I want to add the "Click me" button on the last item added after the first element is initially added. Currently the "click-me" button is appearing at the bottom. For the first element the button may appear this way but from subsequent elements the button must be on the last added item.

```js
$('#clickMe').click(function() {
    $('#Demosss').append($('<li  class="flex-item">').text('dar'));
});
```

```css
.flex-container {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row; /* Safari */
    flex-direction:  row;
    flex-wrap:  wrap;
}
.flex-item {
    background: tomato;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    line-height: 150px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    
}
ul li{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="Demosss" class="flex-container">
<!-- add LI here -->
</ul>


<button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: `on the last added item`: you mean the button must be _in_ the `li` DOM element? or at least appear to be on it? and what is your problem exactly? you can't figure out how to?

Comment: Use prepend() instead of append()

Comment: i believe that's what he meant giorgio. shouldn't be that much more difficult than appending new `<li>` elements. simply append a button and then write a function to remove the buttons from all other elements except the last one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```js
$('#clickMe').click(function() {
    $('#Demosss').append($('<li  class="flex-item">').text('dar'));
    $(this).insertAfter($('[class^="flex-item"]').last());
});
```

```css
.flex-container {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row; /* Safari */
    flex-direction:  row;
    flex-wrap:  wrap;
}
.flex-item {
    background: tomato;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    line-height: 150px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    
}
ul li{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="Demosss" class="flex-container">
<!-- add LI here -->
</ul>


<button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: I want the button to be on the last element and not outside seperately

Answer (score 0):

They are probably many solutions possible. You could use last-child css selector.

```
.flex-item .clickMe {
    visibility: hidden;
 }
.flex-item:last-child .clickMe{
    visibility: visible;
 }
```

But we need to use onclick on the button to execute the function:

```
<button id="clickMe" class="clickMe" onclick="clickMe()">Click Me</button>
```

We had a button in the flex-item that would be hidden if not last:

```
function clickMe(){
        $('#Demosss').append($('<li  class="flex-item">').html('<button class="clickMe" onclick="clickMe()">Click Me</button>dar'));
        $('#clickMe').hide();
    }
```